# sort files in a directory based on partial file name in php

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, glob

I am using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php function to find the files in a directory.
I am getting the following array as result:

```
Array
(
[0] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-0.jpeg
[1] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-1.jpeg
[2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-10.jpeg
[3] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-11.jpeg
[4] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-2.jpeg
[5] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-3.jpeg
[6] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-4.jpeg
[7] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-5.jpeg
[8] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-6.jpeg
[9] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-7.jpeg
[10] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-8.jpeg
[11] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-9.jpeg
)
```

What I want is "To sort the files on the basis of partial text of file names". As in the above array, when you may realize I was supposed to expect the result to be sorted as the `...-0.jpeg, ...-1.jpeg, ...-2.jpeg` not `...-0.jpeg, ...-1.jpeg, ...-10.jpeg`.

I am expecting the following result:

```
Array
(
[0] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-0.jpeg
[1] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-1.jpeg
[2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-2.jpeg
[3] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-3.jpeg
[4] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-4.jpeg
[5] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-6.jpeg
[7] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-7.jpeg
[8] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-8.jpeg
[9] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-9.jpeg
[10] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-10.jpeg
[11] => D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\file_2012-08-09-11.jpeg
)
```

Kindly help, how I can do it using PHP with/without regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `natsort` function that *sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm*

Answer (score 1):

As you have all strings in an array, simply use php's built-in function `sort()`.

It would work like this:

```
sort($array);
```

Since all files are in the same directory, this should solve the incorrect order you have. If it doesn't, you can also try this:

```
//Get rid of directory
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $value=str_replace('D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\\','',$value); //Watch out, the last backslash has to be escaped with another backslash, otherwise the string will not end
}

//Sort only the filenames
$sort($array);

//Prepend directory again
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $value='D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\webroot\batch\temp\\'.$value;
}
```